# Beginner stuck on wordpress custimize

Tags: php, wordpress

I am not sure why this isn't working, not sure if it's bad code or if I'm trying something wrong. Any input would be appreciated.
Here is the code.

```
Class CustomizerNick {
    private $settingName;
    private $settingRefresh;

    private $title;
    public $id;

    public $label;
    public $sectionChoose;
    public $settingLink;

    public $name;
    private $priority;

    public function setSettings($setName, $setR) {
        $this->settingName = $setName;
        $this->settingRefresh = $setR;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setControl($id,  $label, $choose, $link) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->label = $label;
        $this->sectionChoose = $choose;
        $this->settingLink = $link;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setSection($name, $priority) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->priority = $priority;
        return $this;
    }

    public function addSection($wp_customize) {
        $wp_customize->add_section($this->name, array("title" =>"testing","priority" => $this->priority));
        return $this;
    }

    private function addSetting($wp_customize) {
        $wp_customize->add_setting($this->settingName, array("default" => "", "transport" => $this->settingRefresh));
    }

    public function addControl($wp_customize, $ob) {
        $wp_customize->add_control($ob);
    }

    public function mainFunc($wp_customize, $ob){
        $this->addSetting($wp_customize);
        $this->addControl($wp_customize, $ob);
        $this->addSection($wp_customize);
        return $this;
    }
};

function functionName($wp_customize) {
    $img2 = new CustomizerNick;
    $img2->setSettings("grid-pic-2", "refresh")->setControl("picture", "second-grid-item", "a named section", "grid-pic-2");
    $img2->setSection("a named section", "5");
    $ob = new WP_Customize_Image_Control($wp_customize, $img2->id, array( "label" => $img2->label, "section" => $img2->sectionChoose, "settings" => $img2->settingLink));
    $img2->mainFunc($wp_customize, $ob);
}
```

It is not showing any errors, but it is not appearing in the customization tab, not sure if I called the built in wp object right. All the objects are there but doesn't seem to giving any output.

Comment: Please edit your question and format the code in the right way. Kindly tell us what you try to do with this code and in which file you are putting it in. Do you get any errors, or what is happening? Otherwise it will be impossible to answer your question. Please red the guidelines of Stackoverflow 'How to ask good question'

Comment: If anyone is iterested I had to call the new WP image object at the same time as add_control();